EntityFramework.Jet Error on Insert and Update
All I have Visual Studio tied to a local Access Database running student sample database for the time being, as I am trying to get a REST API working with a variety of HTTP clients. This DB has an auto_increment ID field out of the box.
I used EF to Scaffold the database successfully. I can get records, and delete records with no problem, but am getting a strange error on new record insert(IE a post).
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
---> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005): An INSERT INTO query cannot contain a multi-valued field.
 //CODE IS LISTED HERE.
 group.MapPost("/", async (Student input) =>
 {
 //Add Record
  using (var context = new ModelContext())
 {
       context.Students.Add(input);
       context.Attach(input);
       await context.SaveChangesAsync();
       return TypedResults.Created($"/api/Store/{input.Id}", input);
  }
  })
  .WithName("CreateStudent")
  .WithOpenApi();


In JetConfiguration there is ShowSqlStatement property. Enabling it, you can see the SQL query before posting to the OleDb provider. Can you check if it is correct?

Ok This is closed. The Issue is the Default Model for the API has a get/set on an autoincrement field. Changing the Id field to get only allowed me to save the records.
You can close this out.
